# Plotting elements of a list through time (ticks)

Tags: netlogo

I would need to study the distribution through time of items that are selected from  a list, based on agent source’s breed  (women and men).

At each tick, a breed woman or man creates a new object that is added in other turtles’lists. This/these objects can be selected at each step (ticks) by other turtles (women and/or men), spreading within the network.

In the plot, the y-axis should have the number of occurrences (frequency) of each object in the visited turtles (i.e. turtles that have selected that item from their lists).

- Example:

  `object 3` is created by a man, `object 5` is created by a woman.

> ```
> man 2: count 1 object 3 (object 3 created) at tick 1
> woman 4: count 1 object 5 (object 5 created) at tick 3
> ...
> man 2: count 1 object 3 (object 3 picked) at tick 12
> man 2: count 1 object 3 (object 3 picked) at tick 12
> man 2: count 1 object 3 (object 3 picked) at tick 13 
> ...
> woman 31: count 1 object 5 (object 5 picked) at tick 21
> ```

- Plots:

  for object 3, I would have (dots in blue as it was created by a man)

> ```
>  x y
>     1 1
>     2 0
>     3 0
>     ...
>     12 2
>     13 1
>     ...
> ```

and for object 5 (dots in red as it was created by a woman):

```
   x y
    1 1
    2 0
    3 0
    ...
    12 0
    13 0
    ...
    21 1
    ...
```

Do you have any suggestions on how I could plot over time items that are created, then picked by turtles and see, separately, the different distributions over time?

[image]

Comment: This question is very unclear. You have a whole bunch of stuff in there about your analysis - which is going to be in R, not in NetLogo. So your question is probably about how to export certain information from NetLogo to csv. Revise the question to only talk about what you want to export in what format.

Comment: NetLogo is for creating simulations but you can do some plotting and analysis to show what's happening in the model and your edits suggest that it could be done in NetLogo. But I still can't work out what you want to plot. What is your y-axis? Is it something like the average over all turtles of some variable? If so, what variable? If not, what is it?

Comment: My y-axis is the frequency of the objects picked up from lists, and x-axis is time (ticks). For example: object 1 is picked up once by women 3 at tick=1, then 5 at tick=2, then 2 at tick=3, and so on. What I would need at this point should be something that can store this information in order to consider variables that might be useful for an analysis in R or Python (and in this case I should consider to list object, source, tick, but only for part of code that allows to pick object from lists). But I have no idea on how to do this

Comment: You still have not answered what is being plotted. STOP trying to work out HOW to do it (eg lists) and explain WHAT you want done. From your example, if women 3 picks up object 1 at tick 1 then 5, and object 2 at tick 3, what do you want plotted? Do you want a separate plot for each turtle, or for each breed? If the x-axis is ticks, do you want the y-axis to be the total number of objects picked up (by any turtle) at the specific tick? If so, what does your variable look like that stores the information about who is picking up what object?

Comment: I try to explain what I have done and what I am trying to do. I have three different turtles (objects, women, men). women and/or men may at each tick 1) create these object , or 2) select old objects. In all the two cases, these objects are added to their own lists and in those ones of turtles connected with them. Once an object is created, I would like to follow/monitor it in some how (I thought about plotting it/them), to see how objects created by women and objects created by men are spreading within the network, and this is linked to action 2) as I am considering turtles that are picking

Comment: an object that was created by either a woman or a man. The plot/dstribution that I would like to have in something similar to the plot that I have shown in my post. If I can do it not with a plot but with a monitor on the screen for each object created, is welcomed. I am open on suggestions, but I have no idea on how to do that. I do not know if I can track each single object created and monitor its spread within the network. What I would like done is to see 'life' of objects created by women and 'life' of objects created by men.

Comment: "if women 3 picks up object 1 at tick 1 then 5, and object 2 at tick 3, what do you want plotted?" on the x-axis I should have time (ticks) and on the y-axis the distribution over time (number of times an (specific) object created by a woman/women and another one created by a man /men were selected by turtles. In your example, I would have plotted object 1 (created let's say by a man) and object 2 (e.g. created by a woman): on x-axis at tick 1 I should have on the y-axis 1 (as we are considering only woman 3, but if I had other turtles that picked this item, would have been

Comment: the sum/count of turtles that picked this item).This should be represented by blue line/dots as I am considering an object (object 1) created by a man, if at `tick=2` other two turtles select this item, then I should have a dot at `y=2`, and so on...If at `tick=3`, `woman 3` selects `object 2`, created by a `woman`,I should have a red dot at `y=1`. If at `tick 4`, other five turtles select this item,I should have at `tick 4` a (red) dot at `y=5`, and so on...I hope this can help answer your questions.Right now, in my list I have strings like `[(object 1),(woman 3), men]`,and I cannot plot them

Comment: Thank you both for your answers. I updated my question to include Val's suggestions. However I am still having difficulties in counting the objects, after they have been created.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is using length filter in order to get the count of objects created by either men or women (if I understood well, this is `item 2` in your list example):

```
let selected (list item 0 list_1 item 1 list_1 item 2 list_1) 
ifelse item 2 list_1 = women [
       set list_1_w fput selected list_1_w
       print (word "List objects created by women: " list_1_w)
       let list_count_w (length (filter [a -> item 2 a = women] list_1_w)) /* added */
       ]
       [ set list_1_m fput selected list_1_m 
         print (word "List objects created by men: " list_1_m) 
         let list_count_m (length (filter [a -> item 2 a = men] list_1_m)) /* added */
       ]
```

The two `let`variables above return a count of objects created by women or men. This count considers only breed women and men, not distinguishing between objects created by woman `x` and objects created by man `x`. About plotting them, probably you should count all of them at each tick in order to have a chronology of the number of events (objects) selected through time by agents. 
To track each object, an idea would be to create a temporary plot pen that can track all objects:

```
ask turtles [ /* here you should distinguish between objects created by women and objects created by men */
  create-temporary-plot-pen (word who)
  set-plot-pen-color color
  plotxy ticks ___ /* you should add here variable that you want to consider */
]
```

The code above can create a multiplot to track all objects (but you will need to label them and keep track when they're selected).
It's just an idea. You (or someone else in the community) should change accordingly the code above to consider the different breeds and how to track these objects through time.

I hope this can be of some help!

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't seem to get you to understand my questions, I have a different suggestion. Stop trying to do a plot. Instead, do a monitor on the screen that does the calculation (at each tick) of whatever it is you are trying to plot. You can have one monitor for each breed. Once you have the monitor working, just use the same code as the pen in a plot.